# Game engine for augmented reality

Tags: model, game-engine, augmented-reality, openscenegraph

For an [augmented reality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality) project I want to display a high resolution live camera feed. Then in front of this I want to display a model than can be manipulated (translate, stretch, etc) in real time.

I was going to use [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/) but realized it will be a lot of work to get the manipulations working. So I would prefer a more high level solution.

Could anyone recommend a game engine from their experience that would support the above features?
Or else a way to interface with a CAD app to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at this project [Goblin XNA](http://graphics.cs.columbia.edu/projects/goblin/goblinXNA.htm). This is open source project uses XNA and augemented reality.

They have developed serverl demo apps with the Goblin framework. Its promising. You can download the code from this [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/goblinxna) link.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FLARToolkit with PaperVision3D. You have methods to translate, scale, roll, pitch & yaw